# Asignar modelo a variable de session en rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Quisiera saber si es posible guardar en una variable de `session` un objeto artículo por ejemplo tengo este código pero me da este error:

> undefined method `add_cesta' for "#":String

Esto es lo que intento hacer:

Este es mi **controlador**:

```
class TiendaController < ApplicationController


  def index
    @titulo = "Bienvenido a la Tienda"
    @articulos = Articulo.all.order("nombre").page(params[:page]).per_page(4)
  end

  def quienes_somos
    @titulo = "Bienvenido a la Tienda"      
  end

  def contacto
    @titulo = "Bienvenido a la Tienda"
  end

  def anadir_producto
      @articulo = Articulo.find(params[:id])
      @carro = sesion_carrito
      @carro.add_cesta(@articulo)
      flash[:info] ="Producto añadido #{@articulo.nombre}"      
      redirect_to inicio_url
  end

  def ver_carro
    if tenemos_sesion?
      @carro = session[:carro]
    else
      flash[:info] = "Donde Vas! Compra antes"
      redirect_to inicio_url
    end
  end

  def vaciar_carrito
      session[:carro] = nil
      flash[:info] = "Carrito vacio"
      redirect_to inicio_url
  end

  private

  def tenemos_sesion?
    session[:carro]
  end

  def sesion_carrito      
      session[:carro] ||= Carro.new
  end
end
```

esta es mi **clase carro.rb** dentro de models:

```
class Carro
  attr_reader :cesta

  def initialize
    @cesta = []
  end

  def add_cesta(articulo)
    @cesta << articulo    
  end

end
```

Teóricamente debería funcionar, no he conseguido algo que me indique que no se puede pero tampoco algo que lo sustente, alguien me puede indicar si es posible y en caso de que si se pueda que estoy haciendo mal.

Answer (score 0):

Las buenas prácticas dicen que no es recomendable guardar modelos en variables de sesión. Lo que deberías hacer es guardar solamente un arreglo con los id de los artículos.
Algo así sería mejor:

```
session[:carrito] ||= []
session[:carrito] << @artículo.os
```

Y luego cuando deseas trabajar con los artículos puedes recuperarlos usando

```
@articulos_en_carrito = Artículo.where(id: session[:carrito])
```